# Inability to scrape some web content using requests module

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Am trying to **scrape** some content from the web as taught by Automate the Boring Stuff. Am wondering how to solve the **503 Server Error**
Below is the snippet of the code. It is not only this particular URL but almost all the URLs I try throws this error.

```
import requests
re = requests.get('http: //www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd/dp/1593279922/')
re.raise_for_status()
```

requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable for url: [https://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd/dp/1593279922/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593279922)

Comment: What makes you think this is something that can be "solved"?  If the URL is broken, what might you do about it?

Comment: The URL is not broken, it is accessible whenever you click it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of your error using User Agent.

```
headers = 
{
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',
}
import requests   
res = requests.get('http://www.amazon.com/Automate-Boring-Stuff-Python-2nd/dp/1593279922/', headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()
```

Having said that, remember some website wouldn't allow automated activities without permissions. If you look closely at the response of this particular case of yours, you'll find this line.

**"To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com"**

So while some websites would allow crawling and scraping, some wouldn't.
You may check any website's robots.txt route for knowing what is allowed and what is not. For example: https://www.amazon.com/robots.txt

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to add headers including User-Agent and some others, such as Accept, Content-Type, and few more.
The principle is following the network tab in your browser, and see what it says, and then do it in python. For example, the image below
[image]

will be

```py
requests.get(..., headers={
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Type": "..."
    }
)
```

Etc.